# jQuery Mobile changepage makes parent function run twice

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web

Hi all I seem to be having a problem with my jQuery mobile script.

```
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function()
    {
        var count=0;
        var pages = ["#home","#rich","#dan"];
        $('.master').click(function() 
        {
        count=count+1;

            $.mobile.changePage($(pages[count]));

            console.log(count);         

        });

    });
</script>
```

So what will happen is on first click it works. Count goes up to 1 and the page changes to #rich. Second click the count goes to 2 the page flashes real quick to #dan and then flashes right back to #rich and the count goes back down to 1. If i click again i get an error saying

> b.data("page") is undefined

No idea why. Any help?

Comment: I am not too familiar with jquery mobile but does pageinit run every time a new page is loaded? so when page is on #rich coming from home, does pageinit run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Huangism suggested, [pageinit is run every time a new page is loaded](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html), most likely resetting your counter. Try setting up your click event using $(document).ready() or some other event that only fires once.

Comment: I switched to document.ready and it fixed going forwards. I edited my comment to include my code to go backwards which is now giving me the same problem.